# How to hide elements inside a loop with button in lwc?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, salesforcedx, button

I have a list rendered in lwc, and I'm trying to develop a button that hides part of that list.
But I'm having problem, because when I click the button it is hiding all the lists.

```
<template if:true={seeMore} for:each={room.roomAmenities} for:item="roomAmenity">
    <li key={roomAmenity}>
        <span class="roomAmenities">● {comodidadesVerMais}</span>
    </li>
</template>
<lightning-button name="showMore" 
                title="Show More"
                data-record-roomid={room.RoomID}
                onclick={showMore} 
                variant="base"
                class="slds-button botaoVerTodos" 
                label={labelShowMore}>
</lightning-button>
```

JavaScript code

```
seeMore= false;
labelShowMore = 'Show More';
showMore(event) {
    const roomId = event.target.dataset.recordRoomid;
    console.log('roomId ' + roomId);


    for (const room of this.rooms) {
        if (this.seeMore == false && room.RoomID == roomId) {
            console.log('roomId ' + room.RoomID);
            this.seeMore = true;
            this.labelShowMore = 'Show Less';
        }
        else if (this.seeMore == true && room.RoomID == roomId) {
            this.seeMore = false;
            this.labelShowMore = 'Show More';
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

When I click on the button the two lists appear, I'm trying to pass action only on the element that was triggered.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your `seeMore` property is a single variable, which means every single row is tied to this single toggle; toggling this variable will affect all rows. You need one variable per row to have the control you're looking for.

```
<template if:true={room.seeMore} for:each={room.roomAmenities} for:item="roomAmenity">
    <li key={roomAmenity}>
        <span class="roomAmenities">● {comodidadesVerMais}</span>
    </li>
</template>
<lightning-button name="showMore" 
                title="Show More"
                data-record-roomid={room.RoomID}
                onclick={showMore} 
                variant="base"
                class="slds-button botaoVerTodos" 
                label={room.labelShowMore}>
</lightning-button>
```

Then you just need to put that data into your rooms:

```
const roomId = event.target.dataset.recordRoomid;
const room = this.rooms.find((item)=>item.RoomID === roomId);
if(room.seeMore) {
  room.seeMore = false;
  room.labelShowMore = 'Show Show';
} else {
  room.seeMore = true;
  room.labelShowMore = 'Show Less';
}
```

Additional changes may be necessary for your code to make this work that is currently unlisted in your question at the time of this answer, but this is a fundamental part of your problem: whenever you need to toggle something independently of other items, you need multiple variables (in this case, variables stored as part of the list items to render).